# Excel - Number of occurrences of specific day and month between two dates?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a start and end date and I am looking for a solution that indicates how often March 30 is contained between the start and end date.

So for 1 Oct 2020 -> 10 Mar 2021 = 0
So for 1 Oct 2020 -> 1 Apr 2022 = 2

I am looking for a self-contained function not mapping out all the dates in multiple cells and then checking whether any date's month is 3 and day is 30. I tried to play with sequence() but did not get far.

Any slick ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This solves the issue:*

**Situation 1:**

[image]

---

**Situation 2:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Date format in Cells H45 & H46 are `dd/mm/yyyy`.
- Put Day of Month in cell H48 and Month in cell I48, to match with start and end dates.
- Formula in cell H49:

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT((TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT($H$45&":"&$H$46)),"ddmmm")=H$48&$I48)+0)
  ```

**N.B.**

- Formula has `ddmmm` stands for Date or Day of the Month in two digits, as well Month of the year in 3 characters only.
- If you want to use Month's name as full like March then replace `ddmmm` with `ddmmmm`.
- Keep trying different combination as start & end dates, as well day and Month to get different result.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Glad to help you ,,, @Matthias Wolf ,,,  keep asking ☺